# ESLint no-use-before-define with Svelte

Tags: eslint, svelte, svelte-component

When using the ESLint rule `no-use-before-define`, the following Svelte component gets an ESLint error:

```
<script>
    const someVariable = 'hello world'
</script>

{someVariable}
```

```
2:1  error  'someVariable' was used before it was defined  no-use-before-define
```

1. Is this bad practice? Is 'someVariable' actually used before it's defined (doesn't look like it to me)
2. If it's totally fine, is there a way to turn off the rule for this specific case?

I know it's possible to turn of ESLint rules on a per-file basis, but it would be still great to keep the rule on in to warn against the following code:

```
<script>
    const someVariable = helloWorld
    const helloWorld = 'hello world'
</script>

{someVariable}
```

Comment: Could you share your eslint config? I can't reproduce this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using TypeScript, you can use `svelte-check` instead of ESLint to check this rule. Since `svelte-check` is designed to understand Svelte syntax, it understands this pattern correctly. Then, you can just turn off the ESLint rule for Svelte files.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-check